# storing salt in app

Tags: salt, password-based-encryption, password-hashing

I want to create a key for my realm database wich work with AES-256 and for encryption wants a `byte[64]` key.

I read this good question about create a key from 4 digit number: *[“Encryption Key derivation from numeric PIN?”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/encryption-key-derivation-from-numeric-pin?newreg=bf75110f9f074f699ea63afa4489419c)*, and this good article about hashing security: [“crackstation.net : Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right”](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

I understand that a *salt* is some random string that creates every time user change their pass or login. But **where and how should I save the *“salt”* string?**

The article mention above states…

> The salt should be stored in the user account table alongside the hash

…but my database is what I want to encrypt.

Comment: A salt has nothing to do with symmetric encryption. It's unclear why you even think you need a salt for anything to begin with.

Comment: realm for aes256 need a key and key must be byte[64] for generating this key I have a 4 digit pin that user give it to me.for generate the key by suggesting below link I need a salt too but where should I save this salt? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

Comment: The salt can be  public.

Comment: @111 can you please explain more. if salt can be public so what are reasons to create it? article I mentioned above said we create salt because it provides save two same passwords with different hash code which make it hard to attacker to extract pass from the hash if the attacker can find salt so what's point of created at first?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack . In your case maybe you can avoid using a salt.

Comment: @111 It's unclear how that question shows that you can avoid using a salt.

Comment: Yes, the link does not tell anything about avoiding salt. Is my opinion that he can avoid salt. Usually salt is used to keep passwords, not AES-keys. Of course I am not *really* sure that he can avoid salt.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a key for my realm database wich work with AES-256 and for encryption wants a byte[64] key.

AES doesn't work with 64 bytes of key (in all the main modes of operation anyway, I'm excluding SIV mode here). There are 3 key sizes: 128, 192 or 256 bits, which obviously require keys using 16, 24 or 32 bytes of (semi-random) key data.

> I understand that a salt is some random string that creates every time user change their pass or login. But where and how should I save the “salt” string?

A salt is mainly used for Key Derivation Functions, in particular Password Based Key Derivation Functions. The salt can remain public. One common method is to simply prefix the salt to the ciphertext (i.e. the encrypted database in this case).

But first you need to decide if you require a key or a password as input. If it is a key you don't need a salt. You may however require an IV - which is almost but not quite the same thing. For the IV the same thing goes, you can simply prefix it to the ciphertext.

Generally the size of the salt / IV is static, so it is easy to retrieve / remove it without requiring a specific encoding.

Comment: I don't know about AES key sizes but in realm example shown in below link you can see an example of usage which uses 64 bytes as key but
 about salt I still can undrestand porpose of usage of salt if its just prefix of ciphertext. my knowledg of salt is artile i mention and based on that we should save salt somewhere secure https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/encryptionExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/encryptionexample/EncryptionExampleActivity.java